# How to get td values from dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I see a lot of similar questions but not one that directly targets my problem. The business logic of my problem is that I allow the user to open a `jQuery Dialog` where I create table loaded with a data from a database and when the user make a choise I load the selected data info fields from the main screen.

My current problem is with collecting the data from the `<tr>` which happens on button click. If it was a hard coded table I would just:

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){
  var $item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td');
})
```

and then do something with `$item` however the table is created dynamically (from Ajax request) everytime the Ajax request is made the table is destroyed and recreated so basically I can't or at least I don't know a way to use some sort of selector to which to bind the event so I can reproduce the above code.

Instead in the dynamic table I have this:

```
      <td><button onclick="getData();return false">Select</button>
```

The problems with this (at least how I see it) are two - first, the using of `onclick` inside `HTML` element. From what I know it's not a good practice and there are better alternatives and I would appreciate answer showing this. Also, even though I go with this code I'm yet unable to extract the text from each `<td>` in:

```
function getData() {
...
}
```

I tried several approaches including the one which was working with the static table and the binded event handler.

At the end here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfs9dL3u/) example where I think I made it clear what I can and what I can not do, so you can refer to it.

Comment: If you select the parent element where the table is created and bind an event to it like this `$('#temp-table').on('click', 'table button', function(){`, I think that the event it triggered, but I'm not sure. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfs9dL3u/4/).

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Seems legit to me. If you want see `Cerlin Boss`es answer. Pretty close to yours. I can't decide if one is better than the other or are the same..

Comment: He's answer is pretty close to mine, the difference is that I prefer to attach the delegation to the parent element, instead of the document itself. I think that there is no use to bind the event in the entire document, but its a minimal performance concern.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown in fact I tried to attach the delegation to the divI'm using to create the `jQuery dialog` where everything else is appended afterwards but for some reason it didn't work while if I use `document` it's ok... any idea why?

Comment: Nope. Not sure why, but it worked on the fiddle I posted. Anyway, if it works to you, its ok. As I said, its just a minimal concern. I don't think binding event to document would decrease your app performace at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfs9dL3u/1/)

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){
  var $item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td');
})
```

Using the above code you are binding a `direct` event but the one which you want is `delegated` event

To use `delegated` event you should use like

```
$(document).on('click',selector, function(){
  var $item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td');
})
```

so your final code will look something like

```
$(document).on('click','.get-data' ,function(){
    var $item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td');
    $.each($item, function(key, value){
        alert($(value).text());
    })
});
```

`document` can be anything which is parent to the table which is going to be created.

Dont forget to add the selector while adding a new table element

Comment: `delegated event` it is. The code is working now as desired. Thanks.Do you think this is the legit approach when it comes to attaching events to dynamic data. I know that before you could use `live()` for that, but from what I know now it's deprecated so is this now the `jQuery` way to do this?

Comment: yes. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`

Comment: @Cerlin how to get values for all rows at once?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it that way.
You can create your table with the database results like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   // create table row and append it to the table using JQuery
   // next create a td element, append it to the created tr
   // and attach a listener to it
   $('<td/>').html(results[i].textProperty)
             .appendTo($(tr))
             .on('click', getData);
}
```

where getData() is your function.

You can pass arguments to your getData like this:

```
.on('click', {info: results[i].data}, getData);
```

Then you can access them in your function:

```
function getData(event) {
    console.log(event.data.info);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: This way you are creating a listener for each td. An optimization could be to create a listener for the whole class of td elements and to pass data to it via HTML attributes or text value like in the approved answer.

Comment: Nice to see fellow bulgarian :) here - `.on('click', {info: re..` to what are you attaching the event?

Comment: Hey :). The event is attached to the newly created td, like in the first code snippet.

Comment: To be honest this comes a little over complicated for me, but +1 for the alternative approach. Although using delegated event seems much more intuitive so I think I'm gonna stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use this pass object in getdata method

```
$('#build-table').on('click', function(){
        $('#temp-table').append('<table><thead><tr><th>Select</th><th>Name</th>    </tr></thead>' +
        '<tbody><tr><td><button class onclick="getData(this);return false">Select</button></td><td>Name1</td></tr>' +  
       '<tbody><tr><td><button onclick="getData(this);return false">Select</button></td><td>Name2</td></tr>' +
                                '</tbody></table>')
    });

    function getData(ob) {

    var $item = $(ob).closest("tr").find('td');
        $.each($item, function(key, value){
            alert($(value).text());
        })
    }
```